# Should we trust the repository when it comes to invariants?

Tags: domain-driven-design, batch-processing

In the application I'm building there are a lot of scenarios where I need to select a group of aggregates on which to perform a specific operation. For instance, I may have to mark a bunch of `Reminder` aggregates as expired if they meet the expiration policy (there is only one).

I have a `ReminderExpirationPolicy` domain service that is always applied before delivering reminders. This policy does something like:

```
reminderRepository.findRemindersToExpire().forEach(function (reminder) {
    reminder.expire(clockService.currentDateTime());
});
```

The expiration policy is currently duplicated as it exists as a SQL predicate within the `SqlReminderRepository.findRemindersToExpire` method and also within the `Reminder.expire` aggregate's method.

The answer to the question may be strongly opiniated (although there should definitely be pros and cons - and perhaps a widely adopted practice), but should I simply trust that the `Reminder.expire` method will only get called as part of the `ReminderExpirationPolicy` process and trust that the repository implementation will return the correct set of reminders to expire or should I also protect the invariant within the `Reminder` aggregate itself?

NOTE: I am aware that modifying multiple aggregates in a single transaction is sub-optimal and hinders scalability, but it's the most pragmatic solution in my case.

Comment: Are you sure reminders can't be manually expired before their normal expiration date, by an admin for instance? I'm usually careful about invariants that imply time because it's the trickiest constraint to work with.

Comment: @guillaume31 No they cannot get expired manually, but they have other means to prevent sending them although it is not called an expiration. The expiration is automated because the rules under which reminders are still valid are very strict. These are tax filing reminders and there is a reminder sent before the Fiscal Period End (FPE) and one after. If the FPE is over it makes no sense to send the 'before' reminder.

Comment: Usually, expiration would only occur if there was a system problem that prevented to send reminders for a long period of time or if they were left uncorrected for too long.

Comment: @guillaume31 I'll ask it to you as well, but would you try to transform a specification into an AST and then into SQL to prevent duplicating the rules within the repository or that would be a naïve?

Comment: That sounds overcomplicated to me. The thing is, I can't quite figure out what the invariant really is here, if any. Maybe you could reformulate it in your Q?

Comment: @guillaume31 Well the invariant was not really important for the scope of the question as I wanted a general answer. However, in this case the invariant is that a Reminder of type `BEFORE_FPE` may only get expired if `currentDate > FPE and not expiration.expired() and (not deliveryState.sent() or deliveryState.excluded()) and not correctionState.noCorrectionWasFound()`

Comment: I guess that it could make it simpler if I also had a `globalStatus` (most states are exclusive), but that is another question.

Comment: I think the invariant plays a role because we now know that it does not (only) monotonically increase with time. If it did, I think we could have moved the entire expiry responsibility to a separate aggregate. But since `deliveryState` and `correctionState` from the `Reminder` itself are also part of the equation, it seems more difficult to do that without causing cross-aggregate conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I simply trust that the Reminder.expire method will only get called as part of the ReminderExpirationPolicy process and trust that the repository implementation will return the correct set of reminders to expire or should I also protect the invariant within the Reminder aggregate itself?

Short answer: you are backwards.  You *must* protect the invariant within the Reminder *aggregate*; using the policy as a query specification is optional.

The key thing to realize is that, in your scenario, using the policy as a query specification is really is optional.  Eliding persistence concerns, you should be able to do this

```
repo.getAll () { a -> a.expire(policy) ; }
```

with the aggregate declining to change state when doing so would violate the business invariant.

*In general*, the reason that this distinction is important is that any data that you could get by querying the repository is *stale* -- there could be another thread running coincident with yours that updates the aggregate after your query has run but before your expire command runs, and if that coincident work were to change the aggregate in a way that the policy would no longer be satisfied, then your expire command would come along later and threaten to violate the invariant.

Since the aggregate has to protect itself against this sort of race condition anyway, checking the policy in the query is optional.

It's still a good idea, of course -- in the course of normal operations, you shouldn't be sending commands that you expect to fail.

What's really happening, if you squint a little bit, is that the expire command and the query are using the same policy, but where the command execution path is evaluating whether the writeModel state satisfies the policy, the query is evaluating whether the readModel state satisfies the policy.  So it isn't really duplicated logic - we're using different arguments in each case.

> However, where my assumptions are different than yours is that from as far as I can see (assuming optimistic locking), even if the data become stale after aggregates are loaded and that I do not enforce the expiration rule within the aggregate, the operation would still fail because of a concurrency conflict.

Yes, if you have assurance that the version of the aggregate that processes the command is the same as the version that was used to test the policy, then the concurrent write will protect you.

An additional consideration is that you are losing one of the benefits of encapsulation.  If the policy check happens in the aggregate, then you are guaranteed that every code path which can expire the aggregate must also evaluate the policy.  You don't get that guarantee if the aggregate is relying on the caller to check the policy (a variant on the "anemic domain" model).

Comment: Yeah, that it was I thought and it's probably the right way to see it. However, where my assumptions are different than yours is that from as far as I can see (assuming optimistic locking), even if the data become stale after aggregates are loaded and that I do not enforce the expiration rule within the aggregate, the operation would still fail because of a concurrency conflict. Therefore, I can guarantee that if the rule is correct in the repository, it would only be applied when data did not change. That means the query condition in the repository alone is enough to protect the invariant.

Comment: That is, assuming that the query only relies on the data that lives within the `Reminder`'s boundary.

Comment: It is a different question, but would you try to automatically translate policies or specifications automatically by turning them into ASTs and then back to SQL or going down that road would be naïve?