# how to model an entity's property in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a `Survey` model class which has the following four value objects:

- `id`
- `creationDate`
- `comment`
- `answeredDate`

The survey expires after a fixed amount of time, let us say 48h. Then I need to model this, but I don't know where to place it.

- On `creationDate` like a method `hasExpired(now: Date)`?
- As a function of the entity itself, checking `creationDate`?
- Other solutions?

Comment: You may also want to approach this differently. What if you wanted the application to react to the fact the survey did expire? Perhaps there's a survey expiration policy which triggers an event that transitions the survey's state?

Comment: You may find thi interesting. https://kalele.io/modeling-temporal-occurrences/

Comment: Also here's one of my old questions regarding modeling expirations. Perhaps it will spark ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288764/should-we-trust-the-repository-when-it-comes-to-invariants

Comment: You could approach it the same way it is modeled in JSON Web Token. Just store an expiration date-time as an entity's property. Then someone who cares will use it approptiately. Because whether a survey is expired is not important by itself, but in context of some action. E.g. it is expired to submit. Then "submit" command processor should care.

Comment: @iTollu "a survey is expired is not important by itself". It certainly depends on the domain. You may want to constrain operations based off that fact, but you may very well trigger actions too. "when a survey expires, send a notification to the survey's creator" for instance.

Comment: @plalx Exactly. It is some operation that is initiated by a user, or it may be some background process that checks whether it should trigger an action. Anyway, it is some processing happening, that checks whether a survey is expired or not. Even if an entity encapsulates data with actions on it - it still plays a passive role and waits to be initiated by someone from the outside. Then the initiator knows what time it is currently, and whether or not it is past the survey's expiration.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which language you are coding but I will present some sample code in C# but I think it's clear enough to show what I mean. I recommend you to calculate and persist expire time once you create the object because you can use this property in order query your survives based on expire time.

```
public class Survey 
{
    public DateTime CreationDate{get; private set;}
    public DateTime ExpireDate{get; private set;}
    public Survey(...,DateTime creationDate,..)
    {
     //Validations...
     //Some Property Initialization
     this.CreationDate=creationDate
     this.ExpireDate=creationDate.AddHoure(48)

    }
}
```

now you can abstract your business rule as a specification, in your case:"If the expire time is passed so the survey is expired". I will show you what I mean by an example:

```
public class TheSurveyHasBeenExpiredSpecification:Specification<Survey>
{
public Expression<Func<Survey , bool>> Expression => x=> x.ExpireDate <= DateTime.Now;
public bool IsStifiedBy(Survey entity)
{
return Expression.Compile().Invoke(entity);
}
}
```

now you can have fun with your Specification, you can use it either alongside your ORM to retrieve expired surveys records or in your code to make decision if the survey is expired or not in my sample you should pass the entity to "IsStifiedBy" method.
good luck

Answer (score -1):

## Solution 1

Mix of option first and two, here is a pseudo-code:

```
class Survey {
  public bool hasExpired(now: Date) {
    creationDate.modify('+48 hours').isLessThan(now);
  }
}
```

## Solution 2

You can also go for different solution. Your aggregate should have **lifetime** field which will be given when Survey is created. This solution will give you great flexibility.

Let's assume that when you start your project, default lifetime of Survey is 48 hours. So all new Surveys have 48 hours lifetime. But in the meantime, the business want to change it, to 7 days.

Now with previous solution you have a problem. What about current Surveys which did not expire yet or just expired?

I think Surveys created before changes should have still old lifetime (48 hours). If you have lifetime set in your Survey, you have no problem with that. Old Surveys will still have 48 hours but new will have 7 days. You just need to use lifetime field in the method `hasExpired(now: Date)`.

## Solution 3

There is also third solution. It is called Policy. Policies can have encapsulate logic of calculating the lifetime of Survey. So you can have different policies. This will give you even more flexibility.

Comment: good point. What about the '+48 hours'? I'd define it as a constant of the class, so as to avoid magic numbers. But I don't know if it's best practice